# Homebrew - Somehow it happened there is no executable openssl

Tags: macos, homebrew, rvm

System Version OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.5

I installed homebrew and rvm. However, when I try to install anything with rvm (ie. rvm install 2.1.1), it says:

```
Somehow it happened there is no executable 'openssl',
run 'brew doctor' and make sure latest '' is installed properly.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '3' =>
  'Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies.',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Requirements installation failed with status: 12.
```

When I run brew doctor it says "Your system is ready to brew". I tried to change the path for Open SSL using `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and then `brew link --force openssl` but it still gives me the same error message. When I do `which openssl` it still says it is located here: `/usr/bin/openssl`.

Any ideas on what I can do to get the openssl to work with Homebrew?

Full Terminal Below:

```
Last login: Sun Jan 15 20:36:34 on ttys000
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ laurensylvain$ rvm install 2.1.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system....
Installing required packages: readline, openssl.
Somehow it happened there is no executable 'openssl',
run 'brew doctor' and make sure latest '' is installed properly.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '3' =>
  'Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies.',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit  for more information.
Requirements installation failed with status: 12.
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ laurensylvain$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ laurensylvain$ touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ laurensylvain$ source ~/.bash_profile
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ laurensylvain$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/laurensylvain/.rvm/bin:/Users/laurensylvain/.rvm/bin
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ laurensylvain$ brew link --force openssl
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ laurensylvain$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

Comment: Please add your system version (eg. 10.12.2) by editing your question or tagging it correctly (e.g. sierra)!

Comment: I'm currently having a similar issue -- this line seems to be of particular interest:

Libraries missing for ruby-2.3.3: /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries

My system doesn't have a directory called /Users/travis nor a user named travis.

Answer (score 13):

I've absolutely no idea why this issue happened, but making sure I had the latest OpenSSL worked for me.

```
$ brew upgrade
```

Comment: I was surprised this worked for me after all the other solutions did not.

Comment: 'brew upgrade' is what I was missing and fixed this for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue trying to install 2.3.1 with openssl installed (system and homebrew)

I presume you've already solved it, but here's what just worked for me.

```
$ export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
$ export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
$ rvm install 2.3.1 --autolibs=homebrew
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have homebrew

```
brew install openssl
```

or

```
brew install openssl --force
```

Comment: `openssl` is already installed, but hasn't been linked by `brew`. The terminal dump in the question shows the OP attempting `brew link --force openssl` and `brew` complaining that it can't link `openssl`.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue (no executable ssl) when trying to install ruby-2.4.0 through rvm (macOS Sierra).

Did brew update and upgrade, as strugee suggested.

Then it complained about missing libraries for /Users/travis/. Needles to say I have no user named Travis. But the precompiled ruby was being downloaded from https://rubies.travis-ci.org.

Therefore I assume something was wrong in the precompiled version of ruby downloaded from that server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue on MacOS (Sierra 10.12.3) the issue seemed to be that I had installed openSSL via curl (from a previous attempt to install Home Brew) before I had Xcode installed. Here was my fix:

I found the error by running:

```
$ brew doctor
```

It gave me the same output that you received.

I navigated to the directory where openSSL resided, in your case:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
```

From there, I removed the openSSL directory:

```
$ rm -r openssl
```

I then reinstalled the openSSL directory:

```
$ brew install openssl
```

It may be worthwhile to just ensure everything is up to date:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
```

If all is well, try installing ruby again:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.4.0
```

If the above doesn't work, another method would be to ensure you have all system requirements by running the following line of code:

```
$ rvm requirements
```